# to config web garden for testing purposes

Tags: web-garden

I configured my web app to use Web Garden by settings the Maximum worker processes to 3.
So now when I start my application, three worker processes are fired up in IIS 7, but all the requests just go to one worker processes.

My question is there a way to force the iis to use different worker process for each request, because I want to test things like sesisons, static objects etc. work in web garden scenario.

Thanks,
Daljit

Answer (score 0):

When you setup a web garden, IIS automatically handles load balancing of requests. It may appear that all the requests go to a single worker process but that is not true. The first few requests will probably go to only one process but if you perform enough requests, IIS will distribute the load to other worker processes.